# Can not use realm with object mapper swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, realm, objectmapper

I'm using Realm with Object Mapper for JSON Parsing. When I create a model class that Use both Object Mapper and Realm than I get compilation error

`error:must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'QuestionSet'`

```
import ObjectMapper
import RealmSwift

class QuestionSet: Object, Mappable {

    //MARK:- Properties
    dynamic var id:Int = 0
    dynamic var title:String?
    dynamic var shortTitle:String?
    dynamic var desc:String?
    dynamic var isOriginalExam:Bool = false
    dynamic var isMCQ:Bool = false
    dynamic var url:String?

    //Impl. of Mappable protocol
    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    //mapping the json keys with properties
    public func mapping(map: Map) {
        id          <- map["id"]
        title       <- map["title"]
        shortTitle  <- map["short_title"]
        desc        <- map["description"]
        isMCQ   <- map["mc"]
        url     <- map["url"]
        isOriginalExam <- map["original_pruefung"]
    }
}
```

if I use super.init() in init method than I get the compilation error

Case 1:

```
//Impl. of Mappable protocol
 required convenience init?(map: Map) {
    self.init()
}
```

`error:must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'QuestionSet'`

Case 2:

```
 //Impl. of Mappable protocol
 required convenience init?(map: Map) {
    super.init()
}
```

`Convenience initializer for 'QuestionSet' must delegate (with 'self.init') rather than chaining to a superclass initializer (with 'super.init')`

Case 3:

```
//Impl. of Mappable protocol
 required convenience init?(map: Map) {
    super.init()
    self.init()
}
```

`error 1: must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'QuestionSet'`

`Initializer cannot both delegate ('self.init') and chain to a superclass initializer ('super.init')`

`Convenience initializer for 'QuestionSet' must delegate (with 'self.init') rather than chaining to a superclass initializer (with 'super.init')`

Comment: You need a default constructor or whatever your language (Swift) calls it.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce If I use default init() method than I have to implement remaining init methods of Object. That I don't want to implement. So here convenience init() is used

Comment: Hmm... then I'm not sure. Ignore me, Swift is not my forte :D

Comment: "the superclass 'QuestionSet'", you are creating sub class inherit from QuestionSet?

Comment: @YunCHEN Yes Im subclassing the QuestionSet

Comment: Case 1 is working for me without Mappable protocol. I don't have ObjectMapper to test them together.

Comment: @YunCHEN The issue is that I m subclassing the QuestionSet. Without subclassing case 1 is also work fine with ObjectMapper as well.

Comment: got the same issue exactly, when i subclass my User model to any class like LoginResponse: User for the example, i got this error, what should i do in my extends class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this pattern:

I have a `BaseObject` that all my Realm objects inherit from

```
open class BaseObject: Object, StaticMappable {

    public class func objectForMapping(map: Map) -> BaseMappable? {
        return self.init()
    }

    public func mapping(map: Map) {
        //for subclasses
    }
 }
```

Then your class would look like this:

```
import ObjectMapper
import RealmSwift

class QuestionSet: BaseObject {

    //MARK:- Properties
    dynamic var id:Int = 0
    dynamic var title:String?
    dynamic var shortTitle:String?
    dynamic var desc:String?
    dynamic var isOriginalExam:Bool = false
    dynamic var isMCQ:Bool = false
    dynamic var url:String?

    //mapping the json keys with properties
    public func mapping(map: Map) {
        id          <- map["id"]
        title       <- map["title"]
        shortTitle  <- map["short_title"]
        desc        <- map["description"]
        isMCQ   <- map["mc"]
        url     <- map["url"]
        isOriginalExam <- map["original_pruefung"]
    }
}
```